# Graph API - file search folder with images

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For what ever reason /search endpoint is not locating files of type images that have been tagged with specific Column values. Is this a known limitation with graph api?

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on here. How are you querying the API and what you mean by "specific column values"?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{rootDriveId}}/items/{{rootFolderId}}/search(q='BLAH')?select=name,id,file

The files in the folders have a column value = 'BLAH' . The search results are coming only for word, pdf, etc image files with same column value is not returned in the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "column".